# Running a java -jar command from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, jar

Is there a way to execute the following command:

```
java -jar nameofjar.jar some parameters
```

from a batch file? I tried with:

```
start java -jar nameofjar.jar <some parameters>
```

but this doesnt seem to do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.exe -jar "myJar.jar"

should do what you are looking for...